# Deleting Keyboard Settings Every time I Test Custom Keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-simulator, custom-keyboard

Every time I want to test my custom keyboard on the simulator or on my device I have to quit Safari (app I'm using for testing the design), go to: Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Delete my Custom Keyboard (because it's null) -> Add Keyboard -> My Custom Keyboard -> Open Safari -> Test.

Is there a workaround this? Has anyone else experienced this? Currently I'm in production mode and not in debugging mode. When I was in debugging mode the keyboard was way too slow and sometimes didn't even appear. I faced the same problem then as well. [Custom keyboard appears with ~5seconds delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749253/custom-keyboard-appears-with-5seconds-delay)

How would one normally test a keyboard without all restarting and deleting?

Comment: How did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. @SyedSadrulUllahSahad however, this was with a much earlier version of Xcode (almost 2 years ago). Surprised this hasn't been fixed by now though.

Comment: i think this is not for xcode, maybe for os or something else with the keyboard extension feature.@lukaivicev